# Create trending report from multiple tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 10 tables in my system that I need to get some counts from.  The 10 tables we have are one for each month, starting in January until now means we have 10 for now.  These tables contain customers.  Each month some previous customers are no longer customers (we have lost some) and each month we gain some customers.  Overall we are increasing our customer base so each month there will be more total customers than the previous month.  I'd like to do a trending report to show just how many new customers are added to our system each month.

I have these tables in SQL and what I'd like to do is start with the total in January.  Then I need to have the additional count of customers for February, March, April, and so on.  Each month will be compared to the total count of the previous month (March additional members will be compared to the March total mebers to determine the difference).  I'd like to get the output to look like this:

```
Jan Total Members       Feb Add'l Members       March Add'l Members      April Add'l Members
45500                   3300                    2299                        3205
```

Is there a way to put together a query to aggregate this data?  I can easily do a Count(*) on the tables to get a total and use a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL clause to get the actual customers of additional members but I need to manually copy the results.  I'd like to run one query to do the work as we may need to do this over and over again in the future.

Comment: Just how did you come up with a design of a separate table for each month?

Comment: Since we get one file per month, that was just how I started and since I had no idea what the query would look like I wasn't sure how to load the data.  I could certainly combine those into one table

Comment: If you want an answer that provides detailed code, then provide more detail, like either table & column names, or made-up names.  In any case, it would help to know:  (1) Will there eventually be 12 tables (one per month), then no more, or will they continue to accumulate? (2) Are the table names going to change? If they do change, will the names at least be predictable (following a logical pattern)?  (3) In the report, do you want January to always be the first column, or will that column represent `12 months ago`, or what?

Comment: In any case, here's a suggestion in principle, for the report (that may change, based on your replies to the questions above) -- (A) start with a `CREATE TABLE`, that includes one column in the table for each column in your report. (B) `UPDATE` each column in that table, using data from its corresponding month (corresponding table).  (C) Generate your report from that table, after all the updates.